# How do I find an object by its id when the object is inside another object

Tags: javascript, object

I have the following data structure in nested objects:

```
const selectableCards = {
jobType1 : {
    card1 : {
        id : "1",
        category: "Cat1",
        title : "Title1",
        cardText : "Some text.",
    },
    card2 : {
        id : "2",
        category: "Cat1",
        title : "Title2",
        cardText : "Some text.",
    },
},
jobType2 : {
    card1 : {
        id : "3",
        category: "Cat2",
        title : "Title1",
        cardText : "Some text.",
    },
    card2 : {
        id : "4",
        category: "Cat2",
        title : "Title2",
        cardText : "Some text.",
    },
}
```

I need to be able to find a card by id. I have tried examples from...
[How do I find objects with a property inside another object in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31769376/how-do-i-find-objects-with-a-property-inside-another-object-in-javascript) and I can not understand how to translate the answer into a solution. I see there is an ES6 approach to this problem but for the life of me I can not translate the ES6 example to this dataset. How can I do this?

Comment: Is the structure always just job > card, or does the depth vary?

Comment: Each "type" of job has a subset of "jobs" in "card" objects.. each card object always has the unique id. The the depth of objects is always this.

Answer (score 1):

Given the structure you've provided, the following should work:

```
const foundCard =
   Object.values(selectableCards)       // array of values in selectableCards
         .map(Object.values)            // convert each jobType to array of values
         .flat()                        // flatten the outer array
         .find(c => c.id === idToFind); // find the sought value
```

Working example:

```js
const selectableCards = {
  jobType1: {
    card1: {
      id: "1",
      category: "Cat1",
      title: "Title1",
      cardText: "Some text.",
    },
    card2: {
      id: "2",
      category: "Cat1",
      title: "Title2",
      cardText: "Some text.",
    },
  },
  jobType2: {
    card1: {
      id: "3",
      category: "Cat2",
      title: "Title1",
      cardText: "Some text.",
    },
    card2: {
      id: "4",
      category: "Cat2",
      title: "Title2",
      cardText: "Some text.",
    },
  }
};

const idToFind = "3"
const foundCard = Object.values(selectableCards).map(Object.values).flat().find(c => c.id === idToFind);

console.log(foundCard);
```

Note that as TJCrowder has suggested, this is not very performant if there is a very large number of items. In such a case, you're better off using a `for` loop:

```
function findCardById(cards, idToFind) {
    for (const jobType in Object.values(cards)) {
        const found = Object.values(jobType).find(c => c.id === idToFind);

        if (found) { return found; }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Working example:

```js
const selectableCards = {
  jobType1: {
    card1: {
      id: "1",
      category: "Cat1",
      title: "Title1",
      cardText: "Some text.",
    },
    card2: {
      id: "2",
      category: "Cat1",
      title: "Title2",
      cardText: "Some text.",
    },
  },
  jobType2: {
    card1: {
      id: "3",
      category: "Cat2",
      title: "Title1",
      cardText: "Some text.",
    },
    card2: {
      id: "4",
      category: "Cat2",
      title: "Title2",
      cardText: "Some text.",
    },
  }
};

function findCardById(cards, idToFind) {
  for (const jobType of Object.values(cards)) {
    const found = Object.values(jobType).find(c => c.id === idToFind);

    if (found) {
      return found;
    }
  }

  return null;
}

console.log(findCardById(selectableCards, "3"));
console.log(findCardById(selectableCards, "2"));
```

Comment: This is great if you're not dealing with hundreds of thousands of them (which most people won't be). For really large data sets, since it doesn't short-circuit, probably better to use loops.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thank you. I have added an example with short-circuiting.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a recursive approach by looking at the actual object or all values.

```js
const
    find = (object, key, value) => {
        if (!object || typeof object !== 'object') return;
        if (object[key] === value) return object;
        let result;
        Object.values(object).some(o => result = find(o, key, value));
        return result;
    },
    selectableCards = { jobType1: { card1: { id: "1", category: "Cat1", title: "Title1", cardText: "Some text." }, card2: { id: "2", category: "Cat1", title: "Title2", cardText: "Some text." } }, jobType2: { card1: { id: "3", category: "Cat2", title: "Title1", cardText: "Some text." }, card2: { id: "4", category: "Cat2", title: "Title2", cardText: "Some text." } } },
    result = find(selectableCards, 'id', '3');

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) to get an array of all of the values of an object, and the [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method lets you find an entry in an array that matches a test you supply (as a function). So (see comments):

```
function findCard(selectableCards, cardToFind) {
    // Loop through the job(?) objects, which are the values of the
    // `seletableCards` object's properties
    for (const job of Object.values(selectableCards)) {
        // Look for a card in the job's p;roperties' values with a matching `id`
        const card = Object.values(job).find(({id}) => id === cardToFind);
        if (card) {
            // Found it
            return card;
        }
    }
}
```

*(It only looks verbose because of the explanatory comments.)*

Live Example:

```js
const selectableCards = {
    jobType1 : {
        card1 : {
            id : "1",
            category: "Cat1",
            title : "Title1",
            cardText : "Some text.",
        },
        card2 : {
            id : "2",
            category: "Cat1",
            title : "Title2",
            cardText : "Some text.",
        },
    },
    jobType2 : {
        card1 : {
            id : "3",
            category: "Cat2",
            title : "Title1",
            cardText : "Some text.",
        },
        card2 : {
            id : "4",
            category: "Cat2",
            title : "Title2",
            cardText : "Some text.",
        },
    }
};

function findCard(selectableCards, cardToFind) {
    // Loop through the job(?) objects, which are the values of the
    // `seletableCards` object's properties
    for (const job of Object.values(selectableCards)) {
        // Look for a card in the job's p;roperties' values with a matching `id`
        const card = Object.values(job).find(({id}) => id === cardToFind);
        if (card) {
            // Found it
            return card;
        }
    }
}
console.log(findCard(selectableCards, "3"));
```

That implicitly returns `undefined` if it doesn't find the card.

If the data set is **truly** massive (you haven't said it is) and you want to avoid temporary arrays, nested `for-in` loops would do it too:

```
function findCard(selectableCards, cardToFind) {
    for (const outerKey in selectableCards) {
        const job = selectableCards[outerKey];
        for (const innerKey in job) {
            const card = job[innerKey];
            if (card.id === cardToFind) {
                return card;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Live Example:

```js
const selectableCards = {
    jobType1 : {
        card1 : {
            id : "1",
            category: "Cat1",
            title : "Title1",
            cardText : "Some text.",
        },
        card2 : {
            id : "2",
            category: "Cat1",
            title : "Title2",
            cardText : "Some text.",
        },
    },
    jobType2 : {
        card1 : {
            id : "3",
            category: "Cat2",
            title : "Title1",
            cardText : "Some text.",
        },
        card2 : {
            id : "4",
            category: "Cat2",
            title : "Title2",
            cardText : "Some text.",
        },
    }
};

function findCard(selectableCards, cardToFind) {
    for (const outerKey in selectableCards) {
        const job = selectableCards[outerKey];
        for (const innerKey in job) {
            const card = job[innerKey];
            if (card.id === cardToFind) {
                return card;
            }
        }
    }
}
console.log(findCard(selectableCards, "3"));
```

Answer (score 0):

A more basic answer (and maybe more understandable)

```
findCard("2")

function findCard(id){
    for (let i in selectableCards) {
        if(i.card1 && i.card1.id === id) {
            console.log('found in card1');
        } else if(i.card2 && i.card2.id === id){
            console.log('found in card2');
        }
    }
 }
```

There are other ways of doing this for instance using higher order functions, however, this code is provided for you to understand (since you mentioned in your comments)

Answer (score 0):

```js
const selectableCards = { jobType1: { card1: { id: "1", category: "Cat1", title: "Title1", cardText: "Some text.",  }, card2: { id: "2", category: "Cat1", title: "Title2", cardText: "Some text.", }, }, jobType2: { card1: { id: "3", category: "Cat2", title: "Title1", cardText: "Some text.", }, card2: { id: "4", category: "Cat2", title: "Title2", cardText: "Some text.", }, } };

const targetId = '3';

const result =
  Object.values(selectableCards) // Flat the first level (the object is now an array)
  .flatMap(Object.values) // Flat one more level (you can add more exact copies of this line for each additional levels you wish to flat)
  .find(e => e.id == targetId); // Find the target object

console.log(result);
```

Comment: You could change `.flatMap(o => Object.values(o))` to just `.flatMap(Object.values)`.

Answer (score 0):

You could produce a lookup object to quickly lookup cards by their *id*.

```js
const selectableCards = {jobType1:{card1:{id:"1",category:"Cat1",title:"Title1",cardText:"Some text."},card2:{id:"2",category:"Cat1",title:"Title2",cardText:"Some text."}},jobType2:{card1:{id:"3",category:"Cat2",title:"Title1",cardText:"Some text."},card2:{id:"4",category:"Cat2",title:"Title2",cardText:"Some text."}}};

const cardsById = new Map( // or Object.fromEntries(
  Object.values(selectableCards)
    .flatMap(cards => Object.values(cards))
    .map(card => [card.id, card])
);

console.log(cardsById.get("1"));
console.log(cardsById.get("4"));
```

Lookup objects are most effective if you need to lookup data multiple times. You would generate the structure once, then do all your lookups.

Depending on preference and need you could use either a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) or [`Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object). The difference being that `Map` differentiates between `cardsById.get(1)` and `cardsById.get("1")`. While using an `Object` `cardsById[1]` and `cardsById["1"]` are considdered the same.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using a library for that kind of data processing - too easy to get it wrong and it's hard to maintain complex functions. We started using [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan) for most of our data processing needs. It's pretty powerful once you wrap your head around it. Here is how you'd solve your questions

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const find = (id, data) => objectScan(['*.*.id'], {
  abort: true,
  rtn: 'parent',
  filterFn: ({ value }) => value === id
})(data);

const selectableCards = { jobType1: { card1: { id: '1', category: 'Cat1', title: 'Title1', cardText: 'Some text.' }, card2: { id: '2', category: 'Cat1', title: 'Title2', cardText: 'Some text.' } }, jobType2: { card1: { id: '3', category: 'Cat2', title: 'Title1', cardText: 'Some text.' }, card2: { id: '4', category: 'Cat2', title: 'Title2', cardText: 'Some text.' } } };

console.log(find('1', selectableCards));
/* =>
  { id: '1',
    category: 'Cat1',
    title: 'Title1',
    cardText: 'Some text.' }
*/
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@13.8.0"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use library called [d-forest](https://github.com/akarande777/d-forest) to find deeply nested object.