# How can I get sibling value in JS object?

Tags: javascript, object, javascript-objects

How can I get 'Pivot Grid', when I have 7? Is there method or can you help me with function?

```
WIDGET_TYPES = {

    PIVOT_GRID: {
        LABEL: 'Pivot Grid',
        ID: 7,
    },
    DATA_GRID: {
        LABEL: 'Grid',
        ID: 4,
    },
};
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I find objects with a property inside another object in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31769376/how-do-i-find-objects-with-a-property-inside-another-object-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `Object.values` and `find`

`Object.values` - will convert your object to array wiht next structure:

`[{LABEL: 'Pivot Grid',ID: 7,}, ...]`

after conversion you can apply `find` to new generated array.
In the `find` method you will pass your id(7) what need to find

then we need to take label from found element of array

```js
const WIDGET_TYPES = {
    PIVOT_GRID: {
        LABEL: 'Pivot Grid',
        ID: 7,
    },
    DATA_GRID: {
        LABEL: 'Grid',
        ID: 4,
    },
};

const ID = 7;

const foundLabel = Object.values(WIDGET_TYPES).find(i => i.ID === ID)?.LABEL;

console.log('foundLabel: ', foundLabel)
```

Comment: hope now it is clear fir you, if it helps you can mark my anser as correct